# Is it possible to change fonts in multiple notes in Evernote?

Tags: fonts, evernote

Just wondering if it is possible to change fonts and/or font size in multiple notes or entire notebooks?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe so. Other then changing your system wide font, there is no way to do more then one note at a time.